# if ( screen.availWidth > ) disables all scripts?

Tags: jquery, mobile, javascript

I was looking for a way to disable prettyPhoto lightbox on small devices (since the popups were smaller than the displayed images in the gallery on the page, and the thing generally looked ugly that small), and I came across

```
   if ( screen.availWidth > 500 ) { << jquery script code here >> };
```

This neatly fixed things and disabled the gallery script on devices smaller than 500px wide. But it also disabled **all the other** linked js files.

How come adding the availWidth line to the top of 1 script influences everything else?
The order in which the scripts are called doesn't seme to matter (in `<head>`):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

- Only tested with iPhone so I don't know if all devices < 500 ignore javascript like this.

Answer (score 1):

A script that triggers an error would disable all the following scripts in the page.

probably you are executing some code that relies in jQuery or other library, that is not loaded yet, or simply you have some slight error that you didn't notice.

Did you try to put that code after all the linked scripts, and just check if it gets there?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<script>
if ( screen.availWidth > 500 ) {
    alert("Hello!");
};
</script>
```

Comment: I thought there might be an error in the script, but if I put the alert at the bottom, it loads fine.

Comment: Oops, apparently Enter posts the message.
Here's a test page: http://www.corienbennink.nl/en/test.html

I did cut out a lot of non-relevant code from the original prettyphoto.js . Dreamweaver doesn't complain about syntax though.

Comment: let the code there, after you load all other scripts, and add the real code. then, add a breakpoint in the `if` and debug the rest of the code step by step, for sure you will find the line that is wrong.  if you dont know how to debug, go to  [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: *goes to tutorial* - Thanks so far!

Comment: I added a bunch of breakpoints, but the only thing it's complaining about is the minified jquery from the Google API that I'm linking to. I'm linking to 1.7.1 (like the script I use did) - if I change it to 2.0.0 the lightbox function breaks. If I use 1.7.1 everything works fine in the browser (FF/Chrome/IE) and on my iPad, but my iPhone disables all scripts.. - because <500)

Comment: remove the condition (so you can execute in desktop the same lines as in iphone, and debug that lines step by step. the error has to be there!

Comment: Well, it does seem to run the whole pretty photo js file fine - corienbennink.nl/en/test2.html . I removed the alert from the html source and put it at the very bottom of the prettyphoto.js file, the alert shows.... I don't get why all scripts are disabled on my iphone. (I like how the site works there without scripts, but I don't get it..)